# Wrapping an instance in a subclass's constructor before returning

Tags: python, class, constructor, factory, partial

I hope the title isn't too wrong or misleading; I'm not entirely sure what the name is for this kind of thing.

Basically, I've been doing a lot of work with dictionaries (and some subclasses thereof: `defaultdict` and `OrderedDict`, for instance) and am trying to just make a few helper functions which will do some of this lifting for me, while still operating across a number of different types of dictionary. Ideally, I'd like to do this quickly (that is, with some amount of optimization) and of course elegantly. Here's an example of what I have now:

```
def filter_dict(old_dict, keep_keys): 
    return {k:v for k,v in old_dict.items() if k in keep_keys}
```

This works well, but if `old_dict` is anything other than a basic dictionary, I lose that.

Okay, so I can do something like `type(old_dict)({.....})` to wrap the newly created dictionary in old_dict's class's constructor, but that still doesn't work for defaultdicts, which take *as a first argument* a function returning default value. If it were second argument, I could just pass some `*args` or something to a constructor, but this complicates things.

I guess my question is: can I get a partial application to a constructor? Can I get the guts of that instance and call its class constructor with everything intact except for the `items`? In Haskell, I'd do something like `reverse = lambda f, x, *args: f(*args, x)` but that's not even allowed in Python.

What am I missing? Some introspection into the classes? Tinkering with `__new__`? Factory... somethingoranother? I feel really dumb here trying to get something pretty but functional (har).

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I'd copy the original object, then change the copy. In your example:

```
def filter_dict(old_dict, keep_keys): 
    res = old_dict.copy()
    for k in res.keys():
        if k not in keep_keys:
            res.pop(k)
    return res
```

It sounds like your helper functions only know about the things they want to change in `old_dict`, not the things they want to keep the same. So, the safest way seems to be to rely on the `copy` method (or the `copy` module) and then remove or change what you don't want. Otherwise you need some way to recall exactly what arguments were used to create the object, and I don't know if a general method for doing this exists.

Comment: Yeah I've definitely considered this, but it seems really... brutish? And I definitely consider this to be a good learning opportunity, since I've been trying to get into introspection, class layout, etc.

If all else fails, I can just return a deepcopy with del k if k not in keep_keys or some such. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I understand your desire for elegance, but I'd caution you against doing object-oriented design for its own sake, instead of for clarity and/or functionality. The copy constructor does almost exactly what you want - initialize a new object with the same data as the previous one. Personally I find code that uses subtle tricks with __new__ et al to be difficult to read, though sometimes it's necessary of course.